# about asincromicity of ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I bind some javascript code on form submit like this:

```
$('#weather').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(e);
    //some javascript here
    $.ajax(){//ajax call number 1};
    $.ajax(){//ajax call number 2};
});
```

I want to be sure that the first ajax call is completed before starting the second one. 
Do I have to move the second call as a callback of the first one to get it?

Comment: Or use `await`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance ok. I've never used but will give it a look. Any hint?

Comment: @LelioFaieta — https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+await&t=h_&ia=web

Comment: thanks @Quentin that's where I was looking at :-)